# Display Firestore Document in Flat List if date field is equal to today or within 40 days from date it was created

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to show any documents where Date Field is either equal to todays date or within 40 days from when the Date Field in a document was created.

The date field in my documents is called Value and is a timestamp.

I had this working perfectly but then noticed only some documents would show now and then.

I don't understand whats going wrong.

```
getjobs = async () => {

  var today = new Date();
  today.setDate(today.getDate() - 40);
  var dd = today.getDate();

  var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  if(dd<10)
  {
      dd='0'+dd;
  }

  if(mm<10)
  {
      mm='0'+mm;
  }
  today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;

  // console.log(today);

    try {

       const unsubscribe = await firebase.firestore().collection("jobs")
           .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {

                var _jobs = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach( (doc)=> {
                    const job = doc.data();

                    // console.log(job.value.toDate().toLocaleDateString('en-GB'));
                    //
                    //
                    // console.log(this.state.user.company);

                    if(job.email === this.state.user.email && job.jobstatus === "Completed" && today <= job.value.toDate().toLocaleDateString('en-GB') ){
                        _jobs.push({ ...job, id: doc.id });
                    }

                });

                this.setState({
                    jobs: _jobs,
                })
            });
            this.setState({ unsubscribe })

    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error cant get jobs', e);
    }
}
```

[image]

**Flat List**

```
<FlatList data={this.state.jobs.concat(this.state.archived_jobs)} renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.Item(item, index)} keyExtractor={item => item.id}/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your date format. When you put days first, you're giving comparison priority to days. `"11/01/1997"` is after `"10/01/2021"`.

Use `toISOString` (and keep the first 10 characters) instead of `toLocaleDateString`, for both `today` and `job.value.toDate()`.

---

(Untested) code:

```
getjobs = async () => {
  const targetDate = new Date();
  targetDate.setDate(targetDate.getDate() - 40);
  const targetDateString = targetDate.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
    try {
       const unsubscribe = await firebase.firestore().collection("jobs")
           .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
                var _jobs = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach( (doc)=> {
                    const job = doc.data();
                    const jobDate = job.value.toDate();
                    const jobDateString = jobDate.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
                    if (
                      job.email === this.state.user.email &&
                      job.jobstatus === "Completed" &&
                      jobDateString >= targetDateString
                    ){
                        _jobs.push({ ...job, id: doc.id });
                    }

                });
                this.setState({
                    jobs: _jobs,
                })
            });
            this.setState({ unsubscribe })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error cant get jobs', e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did try toISOString originally but didn't think that was the correct way.